# Generate all quarters within a start date and end date

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with of different campaigns. Each campaign has a start date and end date.

```
campaign id | start date | end date |
```

I want to know during which quarters did these campaigns happen.

Ideally it would be something like this - under those quarter columns, It would show a binary variable of 0 and 1.

```
account id | campaign id | start date | end date | 2015q1 | 2015q2 | 2015q3 |...etc
```

For example, if a campaign happens during 1/1/2015 - 5/2/2015, then the result would be:

```
| 2015q1 | 2015q2 | 2015q3 |
| 1      | 1      | 0      |
```

I am using Amazon Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

When putting results into columns, you must hard-code values. For example, this input data:

```
id, start_date,end_date
1,2016-03-23,2016-07-18
2,2016-01-01,2016-01-02
3,2016-10-05,2016-11-05
4,2016-01-01,2016-12-31
```

With this query:

```
SELECT
  id,
  start_date,
  end_date,
  (CASE WHEN start_date < '2016-04-01' AND end_date >= '2016-01-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Q1_2016,
  (CASE WHEN start_date < '2016-07-01' AND end_date >= '2016-04-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Q2_2016,
  (CASE WHEN start_date < '2016-10-01' AND end_date >= '2016-07-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Q3_2016,
  (CASE WHEN start_date < '2017-01-01' AND end_date >= '2016-10-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Q4_2016
FROM campaign
```

Gives this result:

```
1   2016-03-23  2016-07-18  1   1   1   0
2   2016-01-01  2016-01-02  1   0   0   0
3   2016-10-05  2016-11-05  0   0   0   1
4   2016-01-01  2016-12-31  1   1   1   1
```

Unfortunately, there is no SQL trickery that can auto-create the columns for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extract(quarter from date) function as below:

```
SELECT
   campaign_id,
   case when start_quarter=1 and start_year=2015 then 1 else 0 end as q1_2015,
   case when start_quarter=2 and start_year=2015 then 1 else 0 end as q2_2015,
   case when start_quarter=3 and start_year=2015 then 1 else 0 end as q3_2015,
   case when start_quarter=4 and start_year=2015 then 1 else 0 end as q4_2015
FROM (
  SELECT
    campaign_id,
    extract(MONTH FROM start_date) AS start_month,
    extract(YEAR FROM start_date)  AS start_year,
    extract(QUARTER from start_date) as start_quarter,
    extract(MONTH FROM end_date)   AS end_month,
    extract(YEAR FROM end_date)    AS end_year,
    extract(QUARTER FROM end_date) AS end_quarter
  FROM table
) t1
```

or if you prefer an option without hard coding you can simply use the subquery.

```
SELECT
    campaign_id,
    extract(MONTH FROM start_date) AS start_month,
    extract(YEAR FROM start_date)  AS start_year,
    extract(QUARTER from start_date) as start_quarter,
    extract(MONTH FROM end_date)   AS end_month,
    extract(YEAR FROM end_date)    AS end_year,
    extract(QUARTER FROM end_date) AS end_quarter
  FROM table
```

This option will give you a result as below:

```
campaing_id start month start year  start quarter   end month   end year    end quarter
    4   2015    2   4   2015    2
    3   2017    1   3   2017    1
    2   2015    1   3   2015    1
    12  2014    4   12  2014    4
    2   2017    1   2   2017    1
    7   2016    3   8   2016    3
```